# Laravel backpack how to load a crud element by ajax call

Tags: php, laravel-backpack

I have a working page for an element (let's say plan page) which loads the HTML fields as defined with $this->crud->addField([...])

My question is how can I get the same HTML through an Ajax call?
How do I loop and parse the crud elements and get the HTML to return it by ajax?

Versions

```
PHP 7.1
Laravel 5.5 
backpack/generators 1.1.13
backpack/base 0.8.3
backpack/crud 3.3.2
```

**Edit 1**
I am doing in blade

```
@foreach ($crud->getFields('add') as $field)
    <?php
        echo $field['name'];    
    ?>
@endforeach
```

but how do I make it render the field?

**Edit 2**
This line seems to get the fields somehow

```
@include('crud::form_content', ['fields' => $crud->getFields('add')])
```

I might be on the right track?

Answer (score 2):

I don't even know if by that time (that's a very old version, 7+ years) we already had the helper methods, but you should be able to get the defined fields with `$this->crud->fields()`

Cheers